# SolrClient In PHP. How to update a documents in Apache Solr with big amount of SolrInputDocuments

Tags: php, solr

I using SolrClient for PHP and I ran into one problem when inserting a lot of data.

This is my script:

```
$doc = [];
$obj_client = new SolrClient($this->options);
$cityResult = $result_city_array->result(); // number over 37 000
$n = 0;

foreach ($cityResult as $row) {

  $doc[$n] = new SolrInputDocument(); 
  $doc[$n]->addField('id', $row->id);
  $doc[$n]->addField('country_id', $row->country_id);
  $doc[$n]->addField('country', $row->country_name);
  $doc[$n]->addField('city_id', $row->city_id);
  $doc[$n]->addField('city_name', $row->city_name);
  $n++;
}

if (!empty($doc)) {

  $obj_client->addDocuments($doc);
  $obj_client->commit();
}
```

In the foreach loop, the script breaks due to the large amount of documents(more than 37000). Maybe someone came across similar and knows what optimal number of documents should be for one commit? 
For example(something like this):

```
if (count($doc) === 1000) {

   $obj_client->addDocuments($doc);
   $obj_client->commit();
   $doc = [];
   $n = 0;

   //Next row is question too
   $obj_client = new SolrClient($this->options); //Should I refresh SolrClient entity????
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That depends - _what_ is breaking? What's the error?

Comment: RESOLVED!I added condition with count of SolrInputDocument and making commit to 'solr' with portion of data in cycle.